# Laravel custom redirect()->intended

Tags: laravel

I want to be redirected to the email verification page when the user has not verified their email and entered the cart page
Automatically return to the cart page after verifying the email.

the CartController:

```
public function showcart(){
      $user = auth()->user();
      if($user->email_ver !== "OK"){
            return redirect()->route('account.email.verify');
      }
  ...
 }
```

I know I can do this work with set a session, but I want to know how I can do this with the intended method?

Answer (score 0):

Intended method only saves the last page you saw if you call `Auth::guard()->check()` method, when you call this method laravel saves last intended url to session that`s because when you call intended after passing login you will redirect to last page you want to see.

in laravel its like this:

For Laravel 5.3 and above

```
 return redirect()->intended('/home');
```

For Laravel 5 up to 5.2

```
return redirect()->intended('defaultpage');
```

For Laravel 4 (old answer)

```
return Redirect::intended('defaultpage');
```

if you want to do it your self you have to do it by session like what laravel does.

Comment: Ok so I must do from session myself for this work,yes?

Answer (score 0):

You can set next url for redirecting in session storage

In **app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate**

```
$next = ['next' => urlencode(request()->path())];

session()->put('next_url', $next);
```

And redirecting to `$next` after login in `redirect_to` method of `LoginController`

**LoginController**

```
public function redirect_to(){
    $next=session()->get('next_url',null);
    if($next){
        return $next;
    }

    // Return to default route for example *home*
    return self::redirect_to;
}
```